# Trying to get latest status for related shipment but the results I receive are incorrect

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am currently working on a project while trying to learn MySQL and I would like to join three tables and get the latest status for each related shipment. Here are the tables I'm working with (with example data):

**shipments**

| id | consignee | tracking_number | shipper | weight | import_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JOHN BROWN | TBA99900000121 | AMAZON | 1 | 101 |
| 2 | HELEN SMITH | TBA99900000190 | AMAZON | 1 | 102 |
| 3 | JACK BLACK | TBA99900000123 | AMAZON | 1 | 103 |
| 4 | JOE BROWM | TBA99900000812 | AMAZON | 1 | 104 |
| 5 | JULIA KERR | TBA99900000904 | AMAZON | 1 | 105 |

**statuses**

| id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | At Warehouse | at_warehouse |
| 2 | Ready For Pickup | ready_for_pickup |
| 3 | Delivered | delivered |

**shipment_status (pivot table)**

| id | shipment_id | status_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | 2 |
| 10 | 5 | 2 |

*all tables do have created_at and updated_at timestamp columns*

**Example of the results I'm trying to achieve**

| slug | shipment_id | status_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ready_for_pickup | 1 | 2 |
| ready_for_pickup | 2 | 2 |
| ready_for_pickup | 3 | 2 |
| ready_for_pickup | 4 | 2 |
| ready_for_pickup | 5 | 2 |

Here's the query I wrote to try to achieve what I'm looking for based on examples and research I did during the past couple of days. I find that sometimes there is sometimes a mismatch with the latest status that relates to the shipment

```sql
SELECT
  statuses.slug AS slug,
  MAX(shipments.id) AS shipment_id,
  statuses.id AS status_id,
FROM
  `shipments`
     INNER JOIN `shipment_status` ON `shipment_status`.`shipment_id` = `shipments`.`id`
     INNER JOIN `statuses` ON `shipment_status`.`status_id` = `statuses`.`id`
     GROUP BY
       `shipment_id`
```

Comment: Please provide create statements for your tables and sample data.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: How do you know how recent a status is? I'm not seeing a timestamp type column, is it just the most recently issued id (in the case that it's auto increment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we need to reference other fields from the same record that evaluates from the *MAX* aggregation, you need to do it in two steps, there are other ways, but I find this syntax simpler:

```
SELECT
  shipments.id AS id,
  statuses.slug AS slug,
  statuses.id AS status_id,
  shipment_status.shipment_id as shipment_id
FROM
  `shipments`
     INNER JOIN `shipment_status` ON `shipment_status`.`shipment_id` = `shipments`.`id`
     INNER JOIN `statuses` ON `shipment_status`.`status_id` = `statuses`.`id`
WHERE 
   shipment_status.id = (
       SELECT MAX(shipment_status.id)
       FROM `shipment_status`
       WHERE shipment_status.shipment_id = shipments.id
   )
```

[try it out!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b763d4/2)

This query makes the assumption that the `id` field is an identity column, so the `MAX(shipment_status.id)` represents only the most recent `status` for the given `shipment_id`

Comment: @IsekaM don't forget to mark the most useful / correct answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT s.id, st.slug, st.id
FROM shipments s JOIN
     (SELECT ss.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipment_id ORDER BY ss.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM shipment_status ss
     ) ss
     ON ss.shipment_id = s.id JOIN
     statuses st
     ON ss.status_id` = st.id
WHERE ss.seqnum = 1;
```

Also note the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.